Request for Assistance Regarding Fraud and Lost Funds
Subject: Need Help Investigating a Scam
Hi there,
My name is Volodymyr, and I'm facing a serious problem. I recently fell victim to scammers who offered me a scheme involving arbitrage between exchanges. They told me to transfer BTS from MEXC to KAVA on XT.com. I decided to give it a try, but I ended up losing my money.
I suspect the scammers might have exploited some vulnerability in the cryptocurrency transfer system. I really want to figure out where my money went and how this could have happened.
Could you advise me on what to do in this situation? Maybe someone has dealt with something similar or knows how to trace these transactions? I’d really appreciate any help or advice.
Thanks in advance!
Best regards,Volodymyr Skachko






I suggest you ask in the Kava discord or telegram. Also it's better to provide a link to the blockexplorer with all the transactions instead of screenshots.

There are relevant informations in non english language, I suggest to try to translate the app in order to get help from english speakers. To provide the links is also helpful.
